# Setters and Getters on ARC environment

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, automatic-ref-counting

I am still learning some nuances of CocoaTouch. What kind of getters/setters are generated internally for types like float, int, etc., on an ARC environment?

I know that if the property is an object on a non-ARC I may have something like this:

```
- (NSURL *)url {
  if (_url == nil) 
    _url = [[MyURL alloc] initWithURL:url];
  return _url
}

- (void)setUrl:(NSURL *)theUrl {
    if (theUrl != _url) {
      [_url release];
      _url = [theUrl retain];
    }
}
```

but on an ARC environment release and retain cannot be used. What kind of getter/setter is created automatically for an ARC environment on this case.

And what about scalar type like float, int, etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of thoughts:

1. The accessor methods (the getters and setters) for fundamental data types (`int`, `bool`, etc.) are very much like the standard accessor methods for objects, the only difference being is that there are no memory management semantics, as they don't make any sense except within the context of an object. Thus, you'll see no `strong` or `weak` with these fundamental data types. And thus the concept of `retain` is not applicable, either.
2. Behind the scenes, the system generated setter for an object declared as a `strong` property in ARC is not dissimilar to the setter for a `retain` property of an object in non-ARC code. It increases the retain count (a.k.a. "maintains a strong reference"). Now, clearly if you were writing the ARC setter for your `strong` property yourself (which you really shouldn't do), you wouldn't be writing that line of code that says `retain`, but the compiler is effectively doing that for you behind the scenes.
3. I'm not quite sure to make of your getter method, as it doesn't quite make sense. Generally getters are not doing any `alloc` or `init` for you.
4. Your setter is a little closer (and I assume this was for a `@property` declared as `retain`). Clearly, the automatically synthesized setters will automatically pick up the memory lifetime qualifier (e.g. `retain` vs. `assign` vs. `copy` vs. ...)  and generate the appropriate code for you, so it's better to just let it do its own thing.
5. By the way, the actual system generated setter will also include KVO ([key-value-notification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html)) calls, too. You don't need to worry about what KVO is, but the key thing is that you don't want your code littered with your own hand-written setter methods, because when you start using KVO, you'll regret having done so. This is just another reason to let the compiler synthesize it's own accessor methods.

Comment: 3. makes sense to me, it's just a lazily-initializing getter

Comment: @Catfish_Man Perhaps "doesn't make sense" was too strong. But having a getter called `url` that sets ivar `_url` with a variable (ivar? global?) called `url` doesn't seem, with no offense to DD, like a very good implementation to me (actually, for lots of reasons, not just because of the naming issues). I'll use lazy initializing if it's a computationally expensive or memory intensive resource, but doesn't seem prudent here, and if I did do it, I'd be inclined to a slightly different implementation.

Answer (score 4):

ARC handles all the releasing and retaining for you. You should probably just use synthesized getters and setters, but if you aren't doing that, just set the ivar and remove all the other code.